# VS code : cannot jump between header file and related cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have a big c++ project in linux. I try to open this project in VS code in windows using remote ssh. After project loaded, i found it cannot jump between header file and its related cpp files, and also cannot jump to variable definition or implemention.

And i already installed extention c/c++, switcher. But i found right click on a variable, it has only following features. Anyone know how to fix it? This is the first time to use VS code. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed this extension on the **remote server**:

[image]

Comment: No, I did not install any in remote server. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, It works now. But hit another issue that OUTLINE shows 'Loading document symbols for ...'. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I can only point you to [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3245). Also, kindly accept the answer, if it solved your original question!